# Unable to fetch facebook friends information after changing the sandbox mode to live mode.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

A few days back i worked on facebook integration in my phonegap app, using this fetched facebook friends birthday dates. now after changing the app to live mode from sandbox, i logged in using some other facebook id, i'm not able to fetch friends birthday dates instead getting "undefined" error. when i use developers facebook username and password able to get birthday dates. weird kind of issue. please help me.

Comment: Can you post some code, or the error log you're seeing? Most likely those friends don't have their birthday set on Facebook, or are explicitly blocking platform apps from seeing it.